# Calculate CRC in JAVA using byte array

Tags: java, arrays, char, hex, byte

I have changed the CRC function as taking byte array.
The CRC function is as follows:

```
    public class CalculateCRCByte
    {
      /* Table of CRC values for high–order byte */
      static byte auchCRCHi[] = {
        (byte)0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,(byte) 0x40,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0xC0,(byte) 0x80,(byte) 0x41,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0xC0,(byte) 0x80,(byte) 0x41,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,
        (byte)0x40,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0xC0,(byte) 0x80,(byte) 0x41,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,(byte) 0x40,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,(byte) 0x40,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0xC0,
        (byte)0x80,(byte) 0x41,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0xC0,(byte) 0x80,(byte) 0x41,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,(byte) 0x40,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,(byte) 0x40,(byte) 0x01,
        (byte)0xC0,(byte) 0x80,(byte) 0x41,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,(byte) 0x40,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0xC0,(byte) 0x80,(byte) 0x41,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0xC0,(byte) 0x80,(byte) 0x41,
        (byte)0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,(byte) 0x40,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0xC0,(byte) 0x80,(byte) 0x41,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,(byte) 0x40,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,
        (byte)0x40,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0xC0,(byte) 0x80,(byte) 0x41,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,(byte) 0x40,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0xC0,(byte) 0x80,(byte) 0x41,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0xC0,
        (byte)0x80,(byte) 0x41,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,(byte) 0x40,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,(byte) 0x40,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0xC0,(byte) 0x80,(byte) 0x41,(byte) 0x01,
        (byte)0xC0,(byte) 0x80,(byte) 0x41,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,(byte) 0x40,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0xC0,(byte) 0x80,(byte) 0x41,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,(byte) 0x40,
        (byte)0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,(byte) 0x40,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0xC0,(byte) 0x80,(byte) 0x41,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0xC0,(byte) 0x80,(byte) 0x41,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,
        (byte)0x40,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,(byte) 0x40,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0xC0,(byte) 0x80,(byte) 0x41,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,(byte) 0x40,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0xC0,
        (byte)0x80,(byte) 0x41,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0xC0,(byte) 0x80,(byte) 0x41,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,(byte) 0x40,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,(byte) 0x40,(byte) 0x01,
        (byte)0xC0,(byte) 0x80,(byte) 0x41,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0xC0,(byte) 0x80,(byte) 0x41,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,(byte) 0x40,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0xC0,(byte) 0x80,(byte) 0x41,
        (byte)0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,(byte) 0x40,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,(byte) 0x40,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0xC0,(byte) 0x80,(byte) 0x41,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,
        (byte)0x40,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0xC0,(byte) 0x80,(byte) 0x41,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0xC0,(byte) 0x80,(byte) 0x41,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,(byte) 0x40,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0xC0,
        (byte)0x80,(byte) 0x41,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,(byte) 0x40,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,(byte) 0x40,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0xC0,(byte) 0x80,(byte) 0x41,(byte) 0x01,
        (byte)0xC0,(byte) 0x80,(byte) 0x41,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,(byte) 0x40,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,(byte) 0x40,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0xC0,(byte) 0x80,(byte) 0x41,
        (byte)0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,(byte) 0x40,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0xC0,(byte) 0x80,(byte) 0x41,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0xC0,(byte) 0x80,(byte) 0x41,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x81,
        (byte)0x40
      } ;

      /* Table of CRC values for low–order byte */
      static byte auchCRCLo[] = {
        (byte)0x00,(byte) 0xC0,(byte) 0xC1,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0xC3,(byte) 0x03,(byte) 0x02,(byte) 0xC2,(byte) 0xC6,(byte) 0x06,(byte) 0x07,(byte) 0xC7,(byte) 0x05,(byte) 0xC5,(byte) 0xC4,
        (byte)0x04,(byte) 0xCC,(byte) 0x0C,(byte) 0x0D,(byte) 0xCD,(byte) 0x0F,(byte) 0xCF,(byte) 0xCE,(byte) 0x0E,(byte) 0x0A,(byte) 0xCA,(byte) 0xCB,(byte) 0x0B,(byte) 0xC9,(byte) 0x09,
        (byte)0x08,(byte) 0xC8,(byte) 0xD8,(byte) 0x18,(byte) 0x19,(byte) 0xD9,(byte) 0x1B,(byte) 0xDB,(byte) 0xDA,(byte) 0x1A,(byte) 0x1E,(byte) 0xDE,(byte) 0xDF,(byte) 0x1F,(byte) 0xDD,
        (byte)0x1D,(byte) 0x1C,(byte) 0xDC,(byte) 0x14,(byte) 0xD4,(byte) 0xD5,(byte) 0x15,(byte) 0xD7,(byte) 0x17,(byte) 0x16,(byte) 0xD6,(byte) 0xD2,(byte) 0x12,(byte) 0x13,(byte) 0xD3,
        (byte)0x11,(byte) 0xD1,(byte) 0xD0,(byte) 0x10,(byte) 0xF0,(byte) 0x30,(byte) 0x31,(byte) 0xF1,(byte) 0x33,(byte) 0xF3,(byte) 0xF2,(byte) 0x32,(byte) 0x36,(byte) 0xF6,(byte) 0xF7,
        (byte)0x37,(byte) 0xF5,(byte) 0x35,(byte) 0x34,(byte) 0xF4,(byte) 0x3C,(byte) 0xFC,(byte) 0xFD,(byte) 0x3D,(byte) 0xFF,(byte) 0x3F,(byte) 0x3E,(byte) 0xFE,(byte) 0xFA,(byte) 0x3A,
        (byte)0x3B,(byte) 0xFB,(byte) 0x39,(byte) 0xF9,(byte) 0xF8,(byte) 0x38,(byte) 0x28,(byte) 0xE8,(byte) 0xE9,(byte) 0x29,(byte) 0xEB,(byte) 0x2B,(byte) 0x2A,(byte) 0xEA,(byte) 0xEE,
        (byte)0x2E,(byte) 0x2F,(byte) 0xEF,(byte) 0x2D,(byte) 0xED,(byte) 0xEC,(byte) 0x2C,(byte) 0xE4,(byte) 0x24,(byte) 0x25,(byte) 0xE5,(byte) 0x27,(byte) 0xE7,(byte) 0xE6,(byte) 0x26,
        (byte)0x22,(byte) 0xE2,(byte) 0xE3,(byte) 0x23,(byte) 0xE1,(byte) 0x21,(byte) 0x20,(byte) 0xE0,(byte) 0xA0,(byte) 0x60,(byte) 0x61,(byte) 0xA1,(byte) 0x63,(byte) 0xA3,(byte) 0xA2,
        (byte)0x62,(byte) 0x66,(byte) 0xA6,(byte) 0xA7,(byte) 0x67,(byte) 0xA5,(byte) 0x65,(byte) 0x64,(byte) 0xA4,(byte) 0x6C,(byte) 0xAC,(byte) 0xAD,(byte) 0x6D,(byte) 0xAF,(byte) 0x6F,
        (byte)0x6E,(byte) 0xAE,(byte) 0xAA,(byte) 0x6A,(byte) 0x6B,(byte) 0xAB,(byte) 0x69,(byte) 0xA9,(byte) 0xA8,(byte) 0x68,(byte) 0x78,(byte) 0xB8,(byte) 0xB9,(byte) 0x79,(byte) 0xBB,
        (byte)0x7B,(byte) 0x7A,(byte) 0xBA,(byte) 0xBE,(byte) 0x7E,(byte) 0x7F,(byte) 0xBF,(byte) 0x7D,(byte) 0xBD,(byte) 0xBC,(byte) 0x7C,(byte) 0xB4,(byte) 0x74,(byte) 0x75,(byte) 0xB5,
        (byte)0x77,(byte) 0xB7,(byte) 0xB6,(byte) 0x76,(byte) 0x72,(byte) 0xB2,(byte) 0xB3,(byte) 0x73,(byte) 0xB1,(byte) 0x71,(byte) 0x70,(byte) 0xB0,(byte) 0x50,(byte) 0x90,(byte) 0x91,
        (byte)0x51,(byte) 0x93,(byte) 0x53,(byte) 0x52,(byte) 0x92,(byte) 0x96,(byte) 0x56,(byte) 0x57,(byte) 0x97,(byte) 0x55,(byte) 0x95,(byte) 0x94,(byte) 0x54,(byte) 0x9C,(byte) 0x5C,
        (byte)0x5D,(byte) 0x9D,(byte) 0x5F,(byte) 0x9F,(byte) 0x9E,(byte) 0x5E,(byte) 0x5A,(byte) 0x9A,(byte) 0x9B,(byte) 0x5B,(byte) 0x99,(byte) 0x59,(byte) 0x58,(byte) 0x98,(byte) 0x88,
        (byte)0x48,(byte) 0x49,(byte) 0x89,(byte) 0x4B,(byte) 0x8B,(byte) 0x8A,(byte) 0x4A,(byte) 0x4E,(byte) 0x8E,(byte) 0x8F,(byte) 0x4F,(byte) 0x8D,(byte) 0x4D,(byte) 0x4C,(byte) 0x8C,
        (byte)0x44,(byte) 0x84,(byte) 0x85,(byte) 0x45,(byte) 0x87,(byte) 0x47,(byte) 0x46,(byte) 0x86,(byte) 0x82,(byte) 0x42,(byte) 0x43,(byte) 0x83,(byte) 0x41,(byte) 0x81,(byte) 0x80,
        (byte)0x40
      } ;

      static int CRC16(byte[] buffer, int usDataLen)
      {
         byte uchCRCHi = (byte)0xFF ; /* high byte of CRC initialized */
         byte uchCRCLo = (byte)0xFF ; /* low byte of CRC initialized */
         int uIndex ; /* will index into CRC lookup table */
         int i=0;

         while (usDataLen-- > 0) /* pass through message buffer */
         {
          uIndex = uchCRCHi ^buffer[i] & 0xFF ; /* calculate the CRC */
          uchCRCHi = (byte)(uchCRCLo ^ auchCRCHi[uIndex]) ;
          uchCRCLo = auchCRCLo[uIndex] ;
          i++;
         }

        return (uchCRCHi << 8 | uchCRCLo) ;
        }
    }
```

The code used is:

```
byte[] testbuffer = {0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x01, (byte) 0xFF, 0x00};
int crcresult;
crcresult = CalculateCRCByte.CRC16(testbuffer, 6);
System.out.println(crcresult);
```

I have converted the type of "Buffer" in CRC16 from char[] to byte[].

While calculating the CRC when i put 0xFF in 5th byte, the crc calculation is not right. By other method we got CRC  for {0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x01,(byte) 0xFF, 0x00} as " DD FA"
whereas above crc calculation is giving crc as "FF FA".

I think whenever we have to put (byte) type casting in the byte[] , like in the above byte array , testbuffer we have placed (byte) in front of FF, the crc calculation becomes wrong.

The crc calculation was right when char was used instead of byte in above calculation.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Another option

I used the lookup table of

```
http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/51data/CRC16.java.html
```

The code is

```
byte[] bytes1= {0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x01, (byte) 0xFF, 0x00};

int crc = 0x0000;
for (byte b : bytes1) {
    crc = (crc >>> 8) ^ table[(crc ^ b) & 0xff];
}

System.out.println();
System.out.println("CRC16 = " + Integer.toHexString(crc));
```

But the output is

```
CRC16 = e1dd
```

here i think the bytes are reversed . If the bytes are reversed then the output should be FADD

Comment: This has nothing to do with your `byte` and everything to do with the fact that you are trying to insert a value into a location in an array which doesn't exist.

Comment: Which line now causes the exception?

Comment: Are you trying to represent text or binary data? They're very different beasts, and you shouldn't try to mix them. In particular, casting the result of parsing a string to an integer into a `char` is almost certainly inappropriate.

Comment: The last three lines of code don't have anything to do with all other lines above. So if the exception really occures there, remove the upper lines from your question.

Comment: @csmckelvey I need to insert (0xFF) in char array , how can i insert it?

Comment: @isnot2bad . I have added the line, Actually i need the char array to send to Calculate.CRC16 function so i am converting byte array to char array

Comment: @JonSkeet I am trying to represent hex data. But i need to convert it to char to calculate its crc. My CRC function takes char array so i need to convert it char . How can i insert FF to char array

Comment: @user3048644 Yes, but when you take a close look you'll see that the last three lines (the first is the one where you initialize buffer3) do not have anything to do with the rest of your code, so the rest of your code is irrelevant for the exception!

Comment: @user3048644 OK. I can't see any array accessing code now, so this lines CANNOT cause an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException! Please check your code and exception again!

Comment: @user3048644: Your CRC function almost certainly *shouldn't* take a `char[]`. It should take a `byte[]`. I suggest you address that first. I also suspect that by "hex data" you mean "arbitrary binary data". Hex is just one way of representing arbitrary binary data as text... but the data itself isn't inherently hex.

Comment: @JonSkeet , I have changed the crc function and is updated but it is still showing the error. Is my method of calculating CRC16 is not ok ??

Comment: @user3048644: No, I suspect it's not - I suspect you'll find you've got a negative value for `uIndex`, but as you haven't given us the full stack trace, it's hard to say for sure. I would try to find an existing CRC-16 implementation rather than rolling your own.

Answer (score 0):

You are implicitly converting from byte to int for the index:

```
uIndex = uchCRCHi ^buffer[i] ; /* calculate the CRC */
```

Since bytes are signed, when uchCRCHi or buffer[i] is a negative value, uIndex will be negative, too. You need to mask the upper bits to zeros, so index doesn't go outside your arrays:

```
uIndex = (uchCRCHi ^ buffer[i]) & 0xFF; /* calculate the CRC */
```

Comment: it didnot gave out of bound exception error, but the crc calculation is not right using above code. While calculating the CRC when i put 0xFF in 5th byte, the crc calculation is not right. By other method we got CRC for {0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x01,(byte) 0xFF, 0x00} as " DD FA" whereas above crc calculation is giving crc as "FF FA".

The crc calculation was right when char was used instead of byte in above calculation.

Comment: can you give me some better links where i can calculate crc properly for 6 bytes.

Comment: @user3048644 Google helps... maybe this one? http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/51data/CRC16.java.html

Comment: i tried that one but it is not giving the correct crc in my case. but it is also not giving the correct crc. i will update the code that i used above.

Comment: If the bytes are reversed, its probably your *reference* that is inaccurate. It may have simply neglected to mention that it stores the CRC as (CRC ^ -1), or it initializes the initial CRC differently. Without documentation how the CRC should be calculated, you're out of luck. File formats/protocols often have their own quirks how they treat checksums.